# No results with dimensions and metrics

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Why doesn't this combination of dimensions and metrics bring me results?

When adding **dimension_filter** by regular expression it no longer generates results, is that combination possible?

I need to generate a report of page views and total users by date on a certain page.

Could you explain to me in a descriptive way if it is possible what I am trying to obtain?

```
<?php
$propertyId = '123456789';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=343adgb34344.json');

$dateRangeStart = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-46 days'));
$valueRegex = '\/([a-z]|[0-9]|-)*\/([a-z]|[0-9]|-)*\/([a-z]|[0-9]|-)*-2203644$';

run_batch_report($propertyId, $dateRangeStart, $valueRegex);

function run_batch_report(string $propertyId, $dateRangeStart, $valueRegex)
{
    // Create an instance of the Google Analytics Data API client library.
    $client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

    // Make an API call.
    $request = (new BatchRunReportsRequest())
    ->setProperty('properties/' . $propertyId)
    ->setRequests([
        new RunReportRequest([
            'dimensions' => [
                new Dimension(['name' => 'date'])
            ],
            'metrics' => [
                new Metric(['name' => 'totalUsers']),
                new Metric(['name' => 'screenPageViews'])
            ],
            'date_ranges' => [new DateRange([
                'start_date' => $dateRangeStart,
                'end_date' => 'today',
            ])],
            'dimension_filter' => new FilterExpression([
                'filter' => new Filter([
                    'field_name' => 'pagePathPlusQueryString',
                    'string_filter' => new Filter\StringFilter([
                        'match_type' => Filter\StringFilter\MatchType::FULL_REGEXP,
                        'value' => $valueRegex
                    ])
                ])
            ])
        ]),
    ]);

    $response = $client->batchRunReports($request);
    $result = $response->serializeToJsonString();

    print_r($result);
    exit;

}
```

Comment: Use https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/ to find out what combinations are compatible

Comment: @aynber It can be combined, but it responds without content and when I remove dimension_filter it responds with content, and testing in the analytics console it has data available